# automatic ssh login script with expect

Tags: authentication, ssh, expect

I would like to login an ubuntu board via ssh and execute some commands in it. Despite the following code logins it doesnt make a cd or execute the file I want it to. What might be the problem?

```
spawn ssh odroid@172.28.0.6
expect "password:"
send "odroid\r"
interact
expect "odroid@odroid:~$ "
send "cd pixhawk_ws_wstool/devel/lib\r"
interact
send "./slam_demo/slam\r"
interact
```

Comment: 1) Setup authentication using keys. 2) Do not use passwords and make yourself a life much easier and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

No need of `interact`, unless you need manual interaction.

```
# We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$' 
# The last '$' sign is to represent end-of-line
set prompt "#|>|%|\\\$ $"
spawn ssh odroid@172.28.0.6
expect "password:"
send "odroid\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "cd pixhawk_ws_wstool/devel/lib\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "./slam_demo/slam\r"
expect -re $prompt
```